# GCP Run: 503 "Service Unavailable" errors

Tags: google-cloud-run

Hi have a few NodeJS servers on GCP Run and when there is a lot of requests, Google adds more instances.  I've noticed that when they are added, we temporarily get a lot of 503 errors but the adding of instances could be because of instances being added.

Things I have tried to do to fix this:

- Reduce the concurrency from 1000 to 500 to 300.  We are still getting 503 errors but in some cases fewer
- Used [health checks](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/healthchecks) to ping an endpoint to make sure express is running before sending traffic.  This also might have helped but we are still getting quite a few 503 errors.

I expect that we should be able to fix this so that we don't have any 503 errors but we are still getting quite a few.

What else should I try?

##### Update #1:

It takes about 10 to 20 seconds to start:
[image]

##### Update #2:

I noticed that the 503 errors happen in groups and that the requests are not just a few milliseconds which means that they are running when the 503 errors occur.  That means that GCP Run is likely adding instances because of the 503 errors and the 503 errors are not happening when the instances are added.

What can cause a 503 error all of a sudden for an instance that is already running?

Comment: How long does it take for your app to startup and begin responding to requests on cold start?

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for the help. I just updated the question with a screenshot.  It takes about 10 to 20 seconds.

Comment: Can you provide the specific `503` error? Have you checked this link on [troubleshooting Cloud Run issues](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting)?